# querying parse, how can I print the data within a tableView cell in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

Hi guys I'm trying to print my query which Ive created in Parse, here it is 
this works fine and does what i need it to

```
 //store my currentLocations here
var locations : [PFObject] = []    

PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint: 
PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if geoPoint != nil {

            var geoPointLon = geoPoint?.longitude
            var geoPonitLan = geoPoint?.latitude
            var currentLocation = PFGeoPoint(latitude: geoPonitLan!, longitude: geoPointLon!)

            var query = PFQuery(className: "User")
            query.whereKey("currentLocation", nearGeoPoint: currentLocation, withinKilometers: 5.0)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if let myObject = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for objects in myObject {

                        self.locations.append(objects)

                    }

                }

                self.tableView.reloadData()


            })

        }

    }
```

this is my tableview cell and number of rows

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: 
 Int) -> Int {

    return self.locations.count


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"

    return cell

}
```

when running my app "test" does print the correct number of entries so I know my query is working.

My question is how can I print the actual locations from my class "User", column named "currentLocation" within Parse?

if you need any other info just let me know     thanks

Comment: You are creating your cell wrongly.

Comment: hey yep I know, this is a test cell to print the number of queries, need the correct version to display whats in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "currentLocation" column is a string, that's how you get it back.

if it is not a string, then you might need to convert it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.locations["currentLocation"]

    return cell

}
```

Comment: trying to convert via as? String but getting an error, this column is a PFObject and contain geoPoint locations, any thoughts?